# Does TWIG support variadic arguments using the "..." token?

Tags: php, include, twig, variadic-functions

I'd like to provide a variable number of arguments to a function from an `include`, but I am not sure whether TWIG supports the *PHP three-dots token*.

I sure can do

```
{{ callFunction('funcName', arg1, arg2, arg3) }}
{{ callFunction('funcName2', null, true) }}
```

in case I have a `Twig_Function` defined in PHP with variadic arguments

```
public function callFunction($name, ...$arguments)
```

but what if I want to call the function via an `include`?

```
{% set foo = 'bar' %}
{% include 'call_function.twig' with {
    'func_name':'funcName2',
    'arguments': [ null, true ]
%}
```

This seems to not be supported

```
{{ callFunction(func_name, ...arguments) }}
```

How do I pass a variable number of argument to an `include`?

Comment: Twig is a template engine. Prepare your data in controller.

Comment: What about making the function context aware? This way u'd have access to all passed variables and u don't need to pass any extra

Comment: @DarkBee not sure it would work. How to distinguish which context variables are arguments for my function? (I added more examples) - My purpose is to pass the arguments array blindly, without having to access variables by name (```callFunction``` doesn't know the number/names of the *callable*)

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to add variadic functions like that:

```
$twigenv->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction('foo', function ($a1, array $args = array()) {
}, array('is_variadic' => true));
```

Usage:

```
{{ foo(1, 2, a="a", b="b") }}
#{# foo(1, array(0 => 2, "a" => "a", "b" => "b")); #}
```

You can also create [variadic filters](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#variadic-filters):

> When a filter should accept an arbitrary number of arguments, set the
>   is_variadic option to true; Twig will pass the extra arguments as the
>   last argument to the filter call as an array:

```
$filter = new Twig_Filter('foo', function ($file, array $options = array()) {
    // ...
}, array('is_variadic' => true));
```

Then, add the filter to your Twig environment:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter($filter);
```

And then, using it in a template:

```
{{ value|foo(options) }}
```

If this still not enough, you could create your own Tiwg Extension.

> **Note:** Be warned that named arguments passed to a variadic filter cannot be
>   checked for validity as they will automatically end up in the option
>   array.

However, the `...` operator (also known as splat operator, scatter operator or spread operator) as such is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator is now supported in twig 3.0.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#other-operators